# How can I convert a file to binary (vice versa) in dart (Flutter mobile app)?

Tags: flutter, dart, security, epub, bin

I want to make an online eBook app in flutter. So for security purpose I want to convert my .epub files into binary and save it to my phone storage and then open it through my app.

I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: All files are binary. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, actually I want to encrypt my .epub file so that none can access it easily and again decrypt it for my usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to encrypt a file such that noone else can access it then you should go with a package like [file_cryptor](https://pub.dev/packages/file_cryptor). It is really easy to use:

```
void main() async {  
  FileCryptor fileCryptor = FileCryptor(  
      key: "Your 32 bit key.................",  //add any 32 bit string over here
      iv: 16,  
      dir: "example",  
  );  
  
  File encryptedFile = await fileCryptor.encrypt(inputFile: "video.mp4", outputFile: "video.aes");  
  print(encryptedFile.absolute);  
  
  File decryptedFile = await fileCryptor.decrypt(inputFile: "video.aes", outputFile: "video.mp4");  
  print(decryptedFile.absolute); 
}
```